# Image gallery on Joomla

Tags: css, joomla

I am trying to edit the following. The code helps display an image gallery on a Joomla site.

When the image is displayed, previous and next arrows are displayed to cycle through the images in the gallery.

The problem is the previous and next buttons only appear when the mouse hovers near where the buttons appear. I would like the buttons to display all of the time.

```
div.pp_default .pp_top,div.pp_default .pp_top .pp_middle,div.pp_default .pp_top .pp_left,div.pp_default .pp_top .pp_right,div.pp_default .pp_bottom,div.pp_default .pp_bottom .pp_left,div.pp_default .pp_bottom .pp_middle,div.pp_default .pp_bottom .pp_right
    {
    height: 13px;
}

div.pp_default .pp_top .pp_left {
    background: url(../images/prettyPhoto/default/sprite.png) -78px -93px no-repeat;
} /* Top left corner */
div.pp_default .pp_top .pp_middle {
    background: url(../images/prettyPhoto/default/sprite_x.png) top left repeat-x;
} /* Top pattern/color */
div.pp_default .pp_top .pp_right {
    background: url(../images/prettyPhoto/default/sprite.png) -112px -93px no-repeat;
} /* Top right corner */
div.pp_default .pp_content .ppt {
    color: #f8f8f8;
}

div.pp_default .pp_content_container .pp_left {
    background: url(../images/prettyPhoto/default/sprite_y.png) -7px 0 repeat-y;
    padding-left: 13px;
}

div.pp_default .pp_content_container .pp_right {
    background: url(../images/prettyPhoto/default/sprite_y.png) top right repeat-y;
    padding-right: 13px;
}

div.pp_default .pp_content {
    background-color: #fff;
} /* Content background */
div.pp_default .pp_next:hover {
    background: url(../images/prettyPhoto/default/sprite_next.png) center right no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
} /* Next button */
div.pp_default .pp_previous:hover {
    background: url(../images/prettyPhoto/default/sprite_prev.png) center left no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
```

I have tried removing ':hover' from lines 39 and 43 but this just removes the buttons and then they do not appear when you hover near them.

Comment: I would suggest looking for a Javascript file which would probably handle this.

Comment: The javascript probably controls whether the .pp_previous and .pp_next appear on the element.  Can you post URL?  You could probably do them as a div.pp_default .pp_content:before and div.pp_default .pp_content:after but would need to adjust the positioning.